# graphiql only allows query if at least one element of each sublist contains queried field

Tags: json, graphql

I am using graphiQL to debug my react project's graphql query.

This is my query:

```
{
  testdataJson{
    E{
      D{
        A
        B
        entries
      }
    }
  }
}
```

on dataset testdata.json:

```
{
  "E": [
    {
      "D": [
        [
          {
            "A": "Y1",
            "entries": [
              "Z1"
            ]
          },
          {
            "A": "Y2",
            "entries": [
              "Z2"
            ]
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "A": "Y3",
            "entries": [
              "Z3"
            ]
          },
          {
            "A": "Y4",
            "entries": [
              "Z4"
            ],
            "B": true
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "A": "Y5",
            "entries": [
              "Z5"
            ],
            "B": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which gives the error: `Cannot query field \"B\" on type \"TestdataJsonED\".`

If I change the snippet:

```
[
      {
        "A": "Y1",
        "entries": [
          "Z1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "A": "Y2",
        "entries": [
          "Z2"
        ]
      }
],
```

to

```
[
      {
       "A": "Y1",
       "entries": [
          "Z1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "A": "Y2",
        "entries": [
          "Z2"
        ]
        "B": true
      }
],
```

then everything is fine.

This seems weird as I would expect to be able to have lists which don't necessarily contain at least one element with a "B" value. In fact, my JSON data (which I did not create) has this a lot. Alternatively, this is not the cause and I have done something silly!

Cheers,

Edit: related issue - https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2392

Comment: it depends on type definitions ... you can use fragments for optional fields(-ets)

Comment: @xadm not entirely sure what you mean, but you lead me to the issue i linked in the edits, so thank you. The link suggests to "extend the schema to add nullable over the value" which I don't understand either! - are you saying fragments can do this?

Comment: how is the schema defined ?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I'm not sure where I can get this information, I assumed react inferred the schema when the json files are first included? Have managed to fix the initial problem at least, by editing all the json files programatically, following the suspected reasoning in the question

Comment: react is a client (graphiql is a client, too) and can ask for data but available types are defined on server (backend). What kind of graphql server?